# Bizarre Exception from PySpark of Local Mode in Docker Container

Tags: macos, docker, pyspark

I have a **Spark** application inside a **test.py** that I want to execute. Briefly speaking, I had **Spark 2.3.0** installed, then would like to execute **test.py**. When I did it on my developing machine, **Mac Book**, everything is fine. BUT when attempting to do the same thing in a **Docker** container on my **Mac Book**, I would encounter the following exception which I've searched for possible hints from **Google** without triumph.

### Clues Collected So Far

1. Running **test.py** without **Docker** on my laptop would be absolutely fine.
2. It seems to have something to do with record numbers when saving.
   I. There are three actions where all have similar logic. In the **Docker** container, the first action is executed very well. But the next two would fail EVERY TIME when **Spark** tried to save results to **AWS S3**.
   II. If I limit the dataframes as output in the last 2 actions like 5000, the program would be executed very well.

### Logic of Spark Application

Retrieve data from MySQL or S3, do some computation, then store result onto **AWS S3**.

### Exception Message

```
Exception happened during processing of request from ('127.0.0.1', 52218)
2018-04-24 06:17:19,572 678 py4j.java_gateway INFO:Error while receiving.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/py4j/java_gateway.py", line 1062, in send_command
    raise Py4JNetworkError("Answer from Java side is empty")
py4j.protocol.Py4JNetworkError: Answer from Java side is empty
2018-04-24 06:17:19,626 678 root ERROR:Exception while sending command.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/py4j/java_gateway.py", line 1062, in send_command
    raise Py4JNetworkError("Answer from Java side is empty")
py4j.protocol.Py4JNetworkError: Answer from Java side is empty

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/py4j/java_gateway.py", line 908, in send_command
    response = connection.send_command(command)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/py4j/java_gateway.py", line 1067, in send_command
    "Error while receiving", e, proto.ERROR_ON_RECEIVE)
py4j.protocol.Py4JNetworkError: Error while receiving
Traceback (most recent call last):
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "py/apmain.py", line 36, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/socketserver.py", line 317, in _handle_request_noblock
    self.process_request(request, client_address)
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/socketserver.py", line 348, in process_request
    self.finish_request(request, client_address)
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/socketserver.py", line 361, in finish_request
    self.RequestHandlerClass(request, client_address, self)
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/socketserver.py", line 696, in __init__
    self.handle()
  File "/opt/spark/python/pyspark/accumulators.py", line 235, in handle
    num_updates = read_int(self.rfile)
  File "/opt/spark/python/pyspark/serializers.py", line 685, in read_int
    raise EOFError
EOFError
----------------------------------------
    main()
  File "py/apmain.py", line 30, in main
    engine_main.main(sys.argv)
  File "/opt/ap2126/py/dtt/ml/framework/engine_main.py", line 46, in main
    raise e
  File "/opt/ap2126/py/dtt/ml/framework/engine_main.py", line 36, in main
    engine.execute(tags)
  File "/opt/ap2126/py/dtt/ml/framework/engine.py", line 152, in execute
    passing_datas = layer_handler.execute(passing_datas, tags, is_load_cache=True)
  File "/opt/ap2126/py/dtt/ml/framework/layer_handler.py", line 319, in execute
    is_load_cache)
  File "/opt/ap2126/py/dtt/ml/framework/layer_handler.py", line 87, in _execute_workers_as_sequence
    output_data = worker_handler.worker.do_job(input_datas, results)
  File "/opt/ap2126/py/ap2126/label_extraction.py", line 498, in do_job
    self._get_lbls_from_structured_job('mysql')
  File "/opt/ap2126/py/ap2126/label_extraction.py", line 583, in _get_lbls_from_structured_job
    .json(job_save_temp_path)
  File "/opt/spark/python/pyspark/sql/readwriter.py", line 775, in json
    self._jwrite.json(path)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/py4j/java_gateway.py", line 1160, in __call__
    answer, self.gateway_client, self.target_id, self.name)
  File "/opt/spark/python/pyspark/sql/utils.py", line 63, in deco
    return f(*a, **kw)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/py4j/protocol.py", line 328, in get_return_value
    format(target_id, ".", name))
py4j.protocol.Py4JError: An error occurred while calling o818.json
2018-04-24 06:17:23,151 678 py4j.java_gateway ERROR:An error occurred while trying to connect to the Java server (127.0.0.1:38899)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/py4j/java_gateway.py", line 852, in _get_connection
    connection = self.deque.pop()
IndexError: pop from an empty deque

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/py4j/java_gateway.py", line 990, in start
    self.socket.connect((self.address, self.port))
ConnectionRefusedError: [Errno 111] Connection refused
2018-04-24 06:17:23,152 678 py4j.java_gateway ERROR:An error occurred while trying to connect to the Java server (127.0.0.1:38899)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/py4j/java_gateway.py", line 852, in _get_connection
    connection = self.deque.pop()
IndexError: pop from an empty deque

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/py4j/java_gateway.py", line 990, in start
    self.socket.connect((self.address, self.port))
ConnectionRefusedError: [Errno 111] Connection refused
2018-04-24 06:17:23,153 678 py4j.java_gateway ERROR:An error occurred while trying to connect to the Java server (127.0.0.1:38899)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/py4j/java_gateway.py", line 852, in _get_connection
    connection = self.deque.pop()
IndexError: pop from an empty deque

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/py4j/java_gateway.py", line 990, in start
    self.socket.connect((self.address, self.port))
ConnectionRefusedError: [Errno 111] Connection refused
2018-04-24 06:17:23,154 678 py4j.java_gateway ERROR:An error occurred while trying to connect to the Java server (127.0.0.1:38899)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/py4j/java_gateway.py", line 852, in _get_connection
    connection = self.deque.pop()
IndexError: pop from an empty deque

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/py4j/java_gateway.py", line 990, in start
    self.socket.connect((self.address, self.port))
ConnectionRefusedError: [Errno 111] Connection refused
2018-04-24 06:17:23,155 678 py4j.java_gateway ERROR:An error occurred while trying to connect to the Java server (127.0.0.1:38899)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/py4j/java_gateway.py", line 852, in _get_connection
    connection = self.deque.pop()
IndexError: pop from an empty deque

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/py4j/java_gateway.py", line 990, in start
    self.socket.connect((self.address, self.port))
ConnectionRefusedError: [Errno 111] Connection refused
2018-04-24 06:17:23,156 678 py4j.java_gateway ERROR:An error occurred while trying to connect to the Java server (127.0.0.1:38899)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/py4j/java_gateway.py", line 852, in _get_connection
    connection = self.deque.pop()
IndexError: pop from an empty deque

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/py4j/java_gateway.py", line 990, in start
    self.socket.connect((self.address, self.port))
ConnectionRefusedError: [Errno 111] Connection refused
2018-04-24 06:17:23,156 678 py4j.java_gateway ERROR:An error occurred while trying to connect to the Java server (127.0.0.1:38899)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/py4j/java_gateway.py", line 852, in _get_connection
    connection = self.deque.pop()
IndexError: pop from an empty deque

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/py4j/java_gateway.py", line 990, in start
    self.socket.connect((self.address, self.port))
ConnectionRefusedError: [Errno 111] Connection refused
2018-04-24 06:17:23,158 678 py4j.java_gateway ERROR:An error occurred while trying to connect to the Java server (127.0.0.1:38899)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/py4j/java_gateway.py", line 852, in _get_connection
    connection = self.deque.pop()
IndexError: pop from an empty deque

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/py4j/java_gateway.py", line 990, in start
    self.socket.connect((self.address, self.port))
ConnectionRefusedError: [Errno 111] Connection refused
2018-04-24 06:17:23,159 678 py4j.java_gateway ERROR:An error occurred while trying to connect to the Java server (127.0.0.1:38899)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/py4j/java_gateway.py", line 852, in _get_connection
    connection = self.deque.pop()
IndexError: pop from an empty deque

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/py4j/java_gateway.py", line 990, in start
    self.socket.connect((self.address, self.port))
ConnectionRefusedError: [Errno 111] Connection refused
2018-04-24 06:17:23,159 678 py4j.java_gateway ERROR:An error occurred while trying to connect to the Java server (127.0.0.1:38899)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/py4j/java_gateway.py", line 852, in _get_connection
    connection = self.deque.pop()
IndexError: pop from an empty deque

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/py4j/java_gateway.py", line 990, in start
    self.socket.connect((self.address, self.port))
ConnectionRefusedError: [Errno 111] Connection refused
2018-04-24 06:17:23,216 678 py4j.java_gateway ERROR:An error occurred while trying to connect to the Java server (127.0.0.1:38899)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/py4j/java_gateway.py", line 852, in _get_connection
    connection = self.deque.pop()
IndexError: pop from an empty deque

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/py4j/java_gateway.py", line 990, in start
    self.socket.connect((self.address, self.port))
ConnectionRefusedError: [Errno 111] Connection refused
2018-04-24 06:17:23,217 678 py4j.java_gateway ERROR:An error occurred while trying to connect to the Java server (127.0.0.1:38899)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/py4j/java_gateway.py", line 852, in _get_connection
    connection = self.deque.pop()
IndexError: pop from an empty deque

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/py4j/java_gateway.py", line 990, in start
    self.socket.connect((self.address, self.port))
ConnectionRefusedError: [Errno 111] Connection refused
2018-04-24 06:17:23,218 678 py4j.java_gateway ERROR:An error occurred while trying to connect to the Java server (127.0.0.1:38899)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/py4j/java_gateway.py", line 852, in _get_connection
    connection = self.deque.pop()
IndexError: pop from an empty deque

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/py4j/java_gateway.py", line 990, in start
    self.socket.connect((self.address, self.port))
ConnectionRefusedError: [Errno 111] Connection refused
2018-04-24 06:17:23,219 678 py4j.java_gateway ERROR:An error occurred while trying to connect to the Java server (127.0.0.1:38899)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/py4j/java_gateway.py", line 852, in _get_connection
    connection = self.deque.pop()
IndexError: pop from an empty deque

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/py4j/java_gateway.py", line 990, in start
    self.socket.connect((self.address, self.port))
ConnectionRefusedError: [Errno 111] Connection refused
2018-04-24 06:17:23,220 678 py4j.java_gateway ERROR:An error occurred while trying to connect to the Java server (127.0.0.1:38899)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/py4j/java_gateway.py", line 852, in _get_connection
    connection = self.deque.pop()
IndexError: pop from an empty deque

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/py4j/java_gateway.py", line 990, in start
    self.socket.connect((self.address, self.port))
ConnectionRefusedError: [Errno 111] Connection refused
2018-04-24 06:17:23,222 678 py4j.java_gateway ERROR:An error occurred while trying to connect to the Java server (127.0.0.1:38899)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/py4j/java_gateway.py", line 852, in _get_connection
    connection = self.deque.pop()
IndexError: pop from an empty deque

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/py4j/java_gateway.py", line 990, in start
    self.socket.connect((self.address, self.port))
ConnectionRefusedError: [Errno 111] Connection refused
2018-04-24 06:17:23,223 678 py4j.java_gateway ERROR:An error occurred while trying to connect to the Java server (127.0.0.1:38899)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/py4j/java_gateway.py", line 852, in _get_connection
    connection = self.deque.pop()
IndexError: pop from an empty deque

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/py4j/java_gateway.py", line 990, in start
    self.socket.connect((self.address, self.port))
ConnectionRefusedError: [Errno 111] Connection refused
```

### Part of Dockerfile

```
    .
    .
    FROM centos:centos7
    .
    .
    RUN yum -y install https://centos7.iuscommunity.org/ius-release.rpm && \
        yum -y install python36u python36u-pip python36u-devel && \
        python3.6 -m pip install --upgrade pip && \
        echo "export PYTHONIOENCODING=utf-8" >> ~/.bashrc && \
        echo "alias python='python3'" >> ~/.bashrc && \
        # Installation of the Java Runtime Environment
        su -c "yum -y install java-1.8.0-openjdk" && \
        yum -y install mlocate; updatedb && \
        echo "export JAVA_HOME=\"$(locate bin/java | grep jvm | sed 's+/bin/java++g')\"" >> ~/.bashrc && \
        # Installation of Spark for running `pyspark` with success
        curl -s http://ftp.twaren.net/Unix/Web/apache/spark/spark-2.3.0/spark-2.3.0-bin-hadoop2.7.tgz  | tar -zx -C /opt/ && \
        ln -s /opt/spark-2.3.0-bin-hadoop2.7 /opt/spark && \
        echo "export SPARK_HOME=/opt/spark >> ~/.bashrc"; source ~/.bashrc  && \
        echo "export PYTHONPATH="$SPARK_HOME"/python/" >> ~/.bashrc; source ~/.bashrc && \
        echo "export PYTHONPATH="$PYTHONPATH":./py/" >> ~/.bashrc && \
        echo "export PYSPARK_PYTHON=/usr/bin/python3" >> ~/.bashrc; source ~/.bashrc && \
        # For the interaction with AWS S3 on Spark
        curl -s http://central.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/hadoop/hadoop-aws/2.7.3/hadoop-aws-2.7.3.jar -o ${SPARK_HOME}/jars/hadoop-aws-2.7.3.jar && \
        curl -s http://central.maven.org/maven2/com/amazonaws/aws-java-sdk/1.7.4/aws-java-sdk-1.7.4.jar -o ${SPARK_HOME}/jars/aws-java-sdk-1.7.4.jar
    .
    .
    .
```

### How I Run Docker

`docker run -it --rm ${image id}`

Comment: Kindly add details on how you're starting the container (the `run` command or compose file). Also, show the base image used in the Dockerfile.

Comment: It looks like 52218 port is not available on `localhost`. Try executing `lsof -i :52218` inside your container and on your Macbook shell to see whether an application is listening to this port.

Comment: @SaqibAhmed have posted the command I used; I'll check what you mentioned

Comment: Ok. The problem is that your code is trying to access port 52218 and it isn't available on localhost. That's what `Connection refused` means. Are you accessing this port from your code or pyspark is trying to do this?

Comment: pyspark was trying. And in every execution, that port number in the exception would be different. Same loop. First action fine, can see the result on **AWS S3**. Second action, oh oh , about to save the result....boom! What a good friend, Exception.

Comment: Exception happened during processing of request from ('127.0.0.1', 46648)
Exception happened during processing of request from ('127.0.0.1', 46164)

Comment: Oh. I got it. Sorry I missed the `from` in the exception. It means that a connection `from` the localhost is causing the problem. To troubleshoot the problem, try to run a separate spark image and a separate application image.

Comment: It makes more sense anyway to run separate images for each of the services in the system.

Comment: what bothers me is why running my code with the local mode of **Spark** in my laptop is fine while in a container I would encounter this issue. But still thanks all the same, @SaqibAhmed. Appreciate.

Answer (score 3):

This is due to docker daemon killing the companion java process of the pyspark process because of memory limitations of the running container. The python counterpart detects the socket close and throws the EOF. The other exceptions are launched when trying to reconnect to the dead process.

You should check your process memory consumption (specially the java process which actually performs most of the spark operations) and adjust memory settings (--memory , --memory-swap) for your requirements when running the container (https://docs.docker.com/config/containers/resource_constraints/).